# Ngrx store is updated but not displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am currently running through a ngrx/store + RxJS6 course and have made several adjustments to bring them up to date with the latest version. This however means that the code in the solution looks different then mine.

**The problem**

My store successfully gets all the paprticipants and updates the state, however when trying to update the variable `name` to display the name of a participant with an `userId` of `3`, nothing is updated or an error is thrown.

[image: Screenshot of console]

**Thread-section.component.ts**

```
export class ThreadSectionComponent implements OnInit {
userName: string;

constructor(private threadsService: ThreadsService, private store: Store<ApplicationState> ) {
    store
        .pipe(
            tap(state => console.log(state.storeData)),
            filter(state => typeof state.storeData !== 'undefined')
        )
        .subscribe(
        state => {
            this.userName = state.storeData.participants[state.uiState.userId].name;
        }
    );

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.threadsService.loadUserThreads()
        .subscribe(allUserData => this.store.dispatch(
            new LoadUserThreadAction(allUserData)
        ));
}
```

**Reducers.ts**

```
   export const reducers = {
  storeReducers: storeReducer
};

function storeReducer(state: ApplicationState =  INITIAL_APPLICATION_STATE, action: Action): ApplicationState {
  switch (action.type) {
      case LOAD_USER_THREADS_ACTION:
        return handleLoadUserThreadsAction(state, action);
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
function handleLoadUserThreadsAction(state: ApplicationState, action: LoadUserThreadAction): ApplicationState {
  const userData = action.payload;
  const newState: ApplicationState = Object.assign({}, state);
  newState.storeData = {
      participants: _.keyBy(action.payload.participants, 'id'),
      messages: _.keyBy(action.payload.messages, 'id'),
      threads: _.keyBy(action.payload.threads, 'id')
  };
  return newState;
}
```

**Participant.ts**

```
   export interface Participant {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

**Application-state.ts**

```
import {INITIAL_UI_STATE, UiState} from './ui-state';
import {INTIAL_STORE_DATA, StoreData} from './store-data';
export interface ApplicationState {
    uiState: UiState,
    storeData: StoreData
}

export const INITIAL_APPLICATION_STATE: ApplicationState = {
    uiState: INITIAL_UI_STATE,
    storeData: INTIAL_STORE_DATA
};
```

**Ui-state**

```
export interface UiState {
    userId: number;
    currentThreadId: number;
}

export const INITIAL_UI_STATE: UiState = {
    userId: 3,
    currentThreadId: undefined
};
```

**Store-data.ts**

```
    export interface StoreData {
    participants: {[key: number]: Participant};
    threads: {[key: number]: Thread};
    messages: {[key: number]: Message};
}

export const INTIAL_STORE_DATA: StoreData = {
    threads: {},
    messages: {},
    participants: {}
};
```

**Question:**

**My question to you guys is, why is my variable not updated? I've been thinking on the lines of an uncaught typeError, but the fact it doesn't display an error makes me think it's a logical mistake.**

Comment: How you are updating name, are you dispatching an action?

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov in the thread-section.component.ts I'm updating the userName variable and using interpolation I am displaying it on the view.

Comment: If you create a StackBlitz reproduction I could take a look.

Comment: Why do you include skip(2) in the pipe? Have you tried your implementation without skip?

Comment: @timdeschryver https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwqg6e

Comment: @NgocNamNguyen Without the implementation of the `skip` parameter `participants` stays undefined as the first iteration it does not update from the initial state

Comment: @Maartenw, you can solve this problem without using skip.
You can set the participants to empty [] in initialState to make it legit (not undefined), and use filter operator to ignore empty array.

Comment: @NgocNamNguyen TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: @Maartenw  I think you didn't save the stackblitz.

Comment: @timdeschryver I do save it everytime and export it, however it reverts to the default.

Comment: @NgocNamNguyen so I've implemented the filter and the filter works. However it has the same effect as the skip now and I still don't get into the subscribe (as it doesnt define). So the view still is not updated. I will edit the OP code with what I currently have.

Comment: @Maartenw I think you have to fork it first?